# Distribute every n th row to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-extraction

I have terribly unstructured data in a text file which looks like this:

```
661.
Nym Technologies Logo
Nym Technologies
View on LinkedIn
nymtech.net/
info@nymtech.net
Series A
11-50
Blockchain, Information Technology, Messaging, Privacy, Security
Neuchâtel, Neuchatel, Switzerland
Nym Technologies is a privacy-centric startup
8,857
662.
Lingumi Logo
Lingumi
View on LinkedIn
www.lingumi.com
hello@lingumi.com
Series A
11-50
Apps, E-Learning, EdTech, Education
London, England, United Kingdom
Lingumi is an edtech startup that teaches English to kids aged 2 to 6 using an app and a range of physical products.
8,873
```

Is there a way to sort it via python in a way that it displays the company data in columns?
Like this:

```
661.  | Nym Technologies Logo    |  Nym Technologies     |  View on LinkedIn     |  nymtech.net/     |  info@nymtech.net     |  Series A     |  11-50    |  Blockchain, Information Technology, Messaging, Privacy, Security     |  Neuchâtel, Neuchatel, Switzerland    |  Nym Technologies is a privacy-centric startup    |  8,857
```

I know Screenshots are hated, but I could not format it as a table:
[The outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCme0.jpg)

I just find articles describing how to add infinite columns, like this:
[How to make new columns out of every second row in a pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67403174/how-to-make-new-columns-out-of-every-second-row-in-a-pandas-df)

Comment: you linked a question about pandas, but in your question you never mention pandas at all. From what you posted is unclear in what format you have the data. Are this lists of strings? A single multiline string?

Comment: You are right, I updated the question.

Comment: have you tried for example reading the file line by line, appending each line to a list and when your counter reaches 12 moving to a new list? so at the end you end up with a list of lists that you can pass to a pandas dataframe constructor?

Comment: Yes, I think flattened is the correct term. Some data items are missing by company, but the number at the start (661. for example) is an identifier.

Comment: This is actually a super smart idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'SPACE', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']

grouped_data = []
temp_group = []
for item in data:
    if item == 'SPACE':
        grouped_data.append(temp_group)
        temp_group = []
    else:
        temp_group.append(item)
if temp_group:
    grouped_data.append(temp_group)

for group in grouped_data:
    print(' '.join(group))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the contribution! Is it somehow possible to change the "Space" to a three digit number followed by a dot? I thought of something like /d/d/d/.//? Also, the different data items are not seperated, it is rather a list like this:  661.
Nym Technologies Logo
Nym Technologies
View on LinkedIn
nymtech.net/
info@nymtech.net
Series A
11-50
Blockchain, Information Technology, Messaging, Privacy, Security
Neuchâtel, Neuchatel, Switzerland
Nym Technologies is a privacy-centric startup
8,857

Comment: @ADX change the last line to `print(' | '.join(group))`

Answer (score 0):

You should first read file by lines, clean the data, create columns and read the data using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html)
`pip install pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

lines = file.readlines()
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

columns = ['ID', 'Logo', 'Company Name', 'LinkedIn', 'Website', 'Email', 'Funding', 
           'Employees', 'Industry', 'Location', 'Description', 'Followers']

data = [lines[i:i+12] for i in range(0, len(lines), 12)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

---

```
     ID                   Logo      Company Name          LinkedIn          Website              Email   Funding Employees                                                          Industry                           Location                                                                                                           Description Followers
0  661.  Nym Technologies Logo  Nym Technologies  View on LinkedIn     nymtech.net/   info@nymtech.net  Series A     11-50  Blockchain, Information Technology, Messaging, Privacy, Security  Neuchâtel, Neuchatel, Switzerland                                                                         Nym Technologies is a privacy-centric startup     8,857
1  662.           Lingumi Logo           Lingumi  View on LinkedIn  www.lingumi.com  hello@lingumi.com  Series A     11-50                               Apps, E-Learning, EdTech, Education    London, England, United Kingdom  Lingumi is an edtech startup that teaches English to kids aged 2 to 6 using an app and a range of physical products.     8,873
```

**Note**: I am only using the provided data pattern, change of file data structure might produce undesired output. Also I might be wrong with the column names, but you can easily rename them to fit your use-case.

**Here is a test code:**
You can run code **[`Here`](https://www.online-python.com/)** to confirm the output. Change `print(df)` to `print(df.to_string())` in order to see all the printed data.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = """661.
Nym Technologies Logo
Nym Technologies
View on LinkedIn
nymtech.net/
info@nymtech.net
Series A
11-50
Blockchain, Information Technology, Messaging, Privacy, Security
Neuchâtel, Neuchatel, Switzerland
Nym Technologies is a privacy-centric startup
8,857
662.
Lingumi Logo
Lingumi
View on LinkedIn
www.lingumi.com
hello@lingumi.com
Series A  
11-50
Apps, E-Learning, EdTech, Education
London, England, United Kingdom
Lingumi is an edtech startup that teaches English to kids aged 2 to 6 using an app and a range of physical products.
8,873"""

lines = data.strip().splitlines()
columns = ['ID', 'Logo', 'Company Name', 'LinkedIn', 'Website', 'Email', 'Funding', 
           'Employees', 'Industry', 'Location', 'Description', 'Followers']

data = [lines[i:i+12] for i in range(0, len(lines), 12)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

Code should produce the same output as above.